# Is it possible to encrypt communications without an external server?

Tags: encryption, tls

For example, is it possible to connect to a web server that is HTTP-only, absolutely no support for HTTPS, however the client can still connect to the site without worries of MITM attacks, without an external server, or having anything unique on the web server?

Comment: Nice idea but I'm looking for something where it requires no external services, like a phone application. I was thinking if it was possible to encrypt communications without external help and be able to browse all HTTP websites w/ HTTPS.

Comment: if you are going to encrypt, the recipient has to *de*crypt and it needs to be prepared for that

Comment: Unless you are able to tunnel an encrypted peer to peer connection between the server and client, i.e. a VPN  for the client and the server. Otherwise, it is no.  Because even dedicated leased line without encryption still susceptible to MiTM attack.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking; you can send secret and safe messages, but not "standard sites". You can use end to end encryption without https. This is in the same way you can use E2E with postcards or radio broadcasts or [pencil and paper using a simple tool I made](http://nadachat.com/otp/)

While i think PHP and JS can talk to each other (with prior co-operation) securely, you won't be able to serve a normal page using normal browser routines.

It would be possible to build a JS-enabled client that can safely shuttle data back and forth, like I used when I built nadachat.com. That uses a pubkey to ship a a session-only symmetric key. On top of such a system you could build authentication and a web-like user interface, but not use standard anything like links, images, etc.

It's going to be a lot of heavy-lifting on your part to implement such a system. The encryption part is pretty easy, it's making sure you're talking to the right server (authentication/verification) without a cert that's going to be harder. There are challenge-response routines than can handle that, but again, you're really going against the grain and risk rolling out a flawed implementation.

Don't roll your own crypto.

Comment: "i think PHP and JS can talk to each other (with prior co-operation) securely" - No, in the absence of SSL or a secure private connection the "prior cop-operation" is insecure, hence any subsequent interaction  not using SSL or a secure private connection will be insecure. Arguably if the "prior cooperation" is over an independent network from the subsequent interaction, there is some security through obscurity - but this has very limited value.

Comment: @symcbean: i was thinking of the common case of ssh uploads but http fetches; you can upload shared secrets to authenticate/encrypt communication to the client at a later point.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of software on both ends of the connection, no.  HTTPS is the protocol designed to address that gap in HTTP.

If for some reason you need to securely communicate but HTTP is your only choice, (perhaps the reason you are asking is there's a firewall blocking all non-HTTP traffic) consider [HTTP tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel) software.  An HTTP tunnel requires an external proxy server as well as a client-side software component.  These low-level protocol tunnels work by emulating network devices to the OS; they then encapsulate IP packets inside the higher level HTTP protocol being exchanged with the proxy.  You then run ordinary VPN software through the resulting tunnel and your proxy forwards the packets for you, allowing you to securely communicate through your regular VPN provider through an HTTP tunnel.

Comment: Doesn't requiring "an external proxy server" break the OP's requirements of "no external server"?

Comment: Yes. But what he's asking for isn't realistic without it.

Answer (score 1):

To be protected from MITM attacks, the data flow must be encrypted. It can be encrypted at 3 levels:

- the TCP level. That means instead of using a raw socket, you use an  encrypted socket. SSL/TLS in the current standard way for that, and in case of HTTP, is called HTTPS. You could imagine an alternate encryption mechanism for that, but when we come to security, the devil hides in detail, so my advice is: don't unless you are an expert in security and encryption.
- the application level (higher). That means that you use an unencrypted channel, but only exchange encrypted messages. For example, that is exactly what happens when you exchange S/MIME encrypted messages via mail. But I know no direct support for that for HTTP
- the IP level (lower). Provided the both ends (and any router on the way) support it, you can use an [IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) encrypted channel. As the encryption is at a level lower that TCP, you can safely use HTTP over it.

A VPN (or any encrypted tunnel, such as ssh) directly to the server is in fact a variant of the above: you set up an encrypted channel from the client to the server and can then safely pass plain HTTP over it.

Comment: Or, a VPN could be used to prevent MITM at a certain point or along a portion of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for but here it goes.
Disclaimers:

The fact your IP connected to the website and certain pages were visited would still be known.  However the contents of any data posted would not.

Lets say you want to post an sensitive data on a public web site.

You could use a browser extension, we will call my fake extenstion EncryptMe.

Say you goto a forum page.   And enter Please install the Encrypt Me extension @ whatever.com  .  Now the EncryptMe app either generates a random key or gets on from an EncryptMe server possible on cloud computing like amazon,google,microsoft.

Now you have a block of data which looks like random noise.  Its binary so you can't post it.  Problem solved uuencode it.

To normal people reading your post, it reads.

```
Please install the EncryptMe extension
IXI:2>E!1XI:2XI:25N*6DE?BEI+BEI(FXI:2XI:23'GBEI)6XI:2WXH`
`
```

Then share the encryption key via email, print out, or etc with authorized individuals.  The EncryptMe extension could also provide a mechanism for sharing the encryption key.

So it this example the send and receiver web browser would both need EncryptMe installed, but the web server needs nothing. EncryptMe would use /dev/random or the Microsoft, MAC equivalent for an encryption key. Using the same public/private key technology.

1. Private key /dev/random
2. Public key generated based on private key

You can post the public key wherever you want or not.  Maybe the EncryptMe app has a public database users can refer to, but you would choose if your public key was available or not.

If you are in control of the web server, but can't turn on encryption because its an embedded device on a ROM chip or something you could do the same.  You would make index.htm literally have large blocks of uuencodings which **you encoded on your PC** before posting it.

The clients web browser reaching your web site would see:

```
Please install EncryptMe browser extension <FireFox link>, <IE link>, <Safria link>

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M0N*6DN*6DGMC(>*6DN*6DEGBEI+BEI(-"B`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I was looking for a solution where only the sender has the encryption yet the data being sent would be unreadable/encrypted.

Comment: @RobGates    You can encrypt the data using whatever method on your PC.  Then uuencode the binary, and post it.  Then you don't have to give out the key if you don't want to.